# Is there a maximum time that a process can be stopped by kill -TSTP?

Tags: bash, process

let's be a process with pid 5656 a bash script (that calls other script written in fortran) using a huge part of our memory. We want to temporarily stop the process with

```
kill -TSTP 5656
```

and then resume it with

```
kill -CONT 5656
```

Can the process stay stopped for some days? Or is there a maximum time to resume it?
Thank you

Comment: depends on the process -- if it doesn't care about external time then it should be ok.  If its going to be bothered by a bunch of time passing, then it could fail after being continued

Comment: But there's no limit imposed by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the process stay stopped for some days?

Yes.

> Or is there a maximum time to resume it?

No.

I am not aware of any OS that imposes any time limit on the state of processes. You can stop a process for as long as you want.